# Logging Emacs file open/save commands

Tags: emacs

I'm looking to keep a history of file operations in Emacs, in particular file open and save commands, with associated timestamps and pid, has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement it by yourself using [emacs standard hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html).

Something like this:

```
(setq *find-file-list* '())
(setq *save-file-list* '())


(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () 
                             (push (list (buffer-file-name) (time-stamp-string)) *find-file-list*)))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () 
                             (push (list (buffer-file-name) (time-stamp-string)) *save-file-list*)))
```